# Method publishProgress must be called from the worker thread, currently inferred thread is main thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I recently re-imported a perfectly fine android project into Android Studio and it has unilaterally decided to complain (and red under squiggle) code that is DEFINITELY safe.

I get this red squiggle in the IDE every time (but only in `postExecute`):

> Method `publishProgress` must be called from the worker thread, currently inferred thread is main thread

```
private void triggerClick() { 

    final class LoginHttpTask
            extends
            AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Boolean /* Progress */, String /* Result */> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress(true);
         }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String checkPhpResponse) {
            publishProgress(false);
        }   

   } 
   new LoginHttpTask.execute();
}
```

What is the cause and why does the code run perfectly fine anyway?

[image: IDE screenshot. Red squiggle underneath publishProgress method]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linting issue. From the documentation for [`publishProgress(Params...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)) (my bold):

> This method can be invoked from `doInBackground(Params...)` to **publish updates on the UI thread** while the background computation is still running.

So this method is designed to only be called on a background thread, and this is reflected [in the source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) of the method with the `@WorkerThread` annotation:

```
@WorkerThread
protected final void publishProgress(Progress... values) {
    if (!isCancelled()) {
        getHandler().obtainMessage(MESSAGE_POST_PROGRESS,
                new AsyncTaskResult<Progress>(this, values)).sendToTarget();
    }
}
```

So while `doInBackground(String...)` is run on a background thread, `onPostExecute(String checkPhpResponse)` is run on the UI thread as you're meant to update your UI directly within that callback. Because `publishProgress(Params...)` is annotated as `@WorkerThread`, the IDE throws up an error even though the code will compile - it works, but it's bad practice.

Without any further context as to how your `AsyncTask` is being used I can't advise as to how to update your code, but I would advise to avoid using `publishProgress(boolean)` and instead update your UI directly from within `onPostExecute(String)`

Comment: so the answer is `remove it` :D to be honest this code is `SO OLD` now I am literally F2'ing through the whole thing and tidying it up. I don't usually use things like `publishProgress` I prefer to show such things myself so I don't know what it was doing in there

Comment: also I honestly thought that `onPostExecute` was dispatched to the UI thread rather than run on it, that seems a bad way to have written it

Comment: @MrHeelis From what I'm guessing, it was to simplify the process of making a background call e.g. a network request. Fire it off, and then you can directly update then UI when it's done. This was from the very early days of Android though, where there were quite a number of things that now don't make as much sense with the benefit of hindsight...